# Editing via review delivers text area with improper escaped HTML tags

Tags: support, edits, markdown, meta, design

I clicked to edit a comment in review on the prime stackoverflow website.

Original text I had planned to edit was not in a code block (as below for presentation purposes) and was similar to:

```
$content = '<h1>About You</h1> <h4>First Name:</h4> <p>'. $fname .'</p> <h4>Last Name:</h4> <p>'. $lname.'</p> <h4>>Age:</h4> <p>'. $age.'</p>';
```

The text that appeared in the textarea for edit purposes (still not in a code block) was similar to:

```
&#36;content = &#39;&#60;h1&#62;About You&#60;/h1&#62;
&#60;h4&#62;First Name:&#60;/h4&#62;
&#60;p&#62;&#39;. $fname .&#39;&#60;/p&#62;
&#60;h4&#62;Last Name:&#60;/h4&#62;
&#60;p&#62;&#39;. $lname.&#39;&#60;/p&#62;
&#60;h4&#62;>Age:&#60;/h4&#62;
&#60;p&#62;&#39;. $age.'&#60;/p&#62;&#39;;
```

There is apparently an HTML escaping issue here, or this is likely normal because the escaped code was either used originally or converted to escaped html for presentation purposes.  Either way, it felt inconsistent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're talking about [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7885094/problems-with-php-in-a-string-assigned-to-a-php-variable/7885158#7885158). The [source](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/9c8b7ca2-c48d-4ce6-8ca3-90da0f81108f/view-source) actually does look like that -- the OP posted it raw originally, which obviously didn't work, so he [edited it](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/7885158/2) to manually escape all the tags, not realizing that there is a better way to format code

Comment: I guess that's why we review posts by new posters then, eh?  Thanks.